# Folding input type hidden with div

Tags: html, css

GitHub layout uses such constructs for CSRF protection of forms (can be seen in sign up form on main page for example):

```
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input type="hidden" value="somerandombase64" name="authenticity_token">
</div>
```

What is the reason to fold `<input type="hidden" ...>` with inline-styled `<div>`?
Isn't that `<div>` redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained here: [LINK](http://www.ideaforge.org/blog/?p=13)

> Rails’ form tag helper helpfully puts a hidden field in with an authenticity token. Unfortunately, it wraps the hidden field in a div! So even if your form has style=”display:inline”, the div won’t.. and you won’t be able to display a form that doesn’t force a newline.

In other words, the safest way to prevent a newline is by adding those styles  `margin:0;padding:0;display:inline` to the wrapper div.

Comment: `display:inline` appends the element to the current line in the document. To place the element in a **new line** there is `display:block`. Isn't it? please clarify the logic in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary [to be valid] according to the [DTD for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html). While it doesn't matter what the descendants of `form` elements are, the direct child elements must be block-level elements.

Run this against the [W3C Validator Service](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) for further proof:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="hidden">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

as opposed to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="get">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```